# json returned from php cannot be parsed for jQuery dataTables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, datatables

I have a simple mysql database table with library books.  I am using a php page to retrieve the list of books.  This is what it returns:

php get_books.php

```
{"iTotalRecords":"1","aaData":[{"author":"Tim Powers","title":"The Anubis Gates","genre":"Fiction","publisher":null,"year":null,"location":"Bookshelf","notes":null}]}
```

In jQuery dataTables, I have:

```
<script >
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#books').DataTable({
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "./get_books.php"
    });
});
</script>
```

When I run the web page with that script I get an alert:

DataTables warning (table id = 'books'): DataTables warning: JSON data from server could not be parsed. This is caused by a JSON formatting error.

I can't find what the formatting error is.  How should the data be formatted.

Here is the php page that does the return of the JSON data:

```
<?php
    $page = isset($_POST['page']) ? intval($_POST['page']) : 1;
    $rows = isset($_POST['rows']) ? intval($_POST['rows']) : 10;
    $offset = ($page-1)*$rows;
    $result = array();

    include 'conn.php';

    $rs = mysql_query("select count(*) from books");
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($rs);
    $result["iTotalRecords"] = $row[0];
    $rs = mysql_query("select * from books limit $offset,$rows");

    $items = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_object($rs)){
        array_push($items, $row);
    }
    $result["aaData"] = $items;

    echo json_encode($result);

?>
```

What should the return look like and how do I produce it?

Comment: Try typeof(data-returned-here) and veryfy that value is object and not string. Sometimes you need set headers for recoinizing a json ,

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  Where do I put the typeof(...).  And what does set headers mean?

Comment: You should inspect the ajax request using your browser's tools and make sure the response is as expected.

Comment: I've looked at the web developer tools in Safari, but haven't found the actual response.  The error seems to indicate that the parser encountered a '>' which is in the php page, not in the response from the page.

Comment: This is what's meant by "set headers": http://stackoverflow.com/a/4064468/622391

Answer (score 0):

There are many problems both with your JS and PHP code.

If you have less than a few thousands records in `books` table I would recommend disabling server-side processing mode by removing `"bServerSide": true` to enable client-side processing mode.

**JavaScript**:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#books').DataTable({
        "ajax": "get_books.php",
        "columns": [
           { "data": "author" },
           { "data": "title" },
           { "data": "genre" },          
           { "data": "location" }         
        ]
    });
});
```

**PHP:**

```php
<?php   
    include 'conn.php';

    $rs = mysql_query("select author, title, genre, location from books");

    $result = array();
    $items = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_object($rs)){
        array_push($items, $row);
    }
    $result["data"] = $items;

    header("Content-type: application/json");
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");

    echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

**HTML**

```
<table id="books" class="display tablesorter">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Author</th>
         <th>Title</th>
         <th>Genre</th>
         <th>Location</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
</table>
```

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mv02n8d4/) for code and demonstration.

If you have more than a few thousands records, you will gain more performance by using server-side processing mode. But in this case I recommend using [ssp.class.php](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/blob/1.10.10/examples/server_side/scripts/ssp.class.php) helper library that comes in jQuery DataTables distribution (see `examples/server_side/scripts` folder).

Comment: Thanks so much Gyrocode!  That got me past the parse error!  I still don't see anything in the DataTable. I'm trying to let jQuery and DataTable do it for me.  With the JSON as you describe above, here's what i have for the table:  <table id="books" class="tablesorter">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr><th>Author</th><th>Title</th><th>Genre</th><th>Location</th></tr>
                                    <tbody>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>

Comment: @JohnWooten, I have updated the answer adding the location column.

Comment: I'm finally able to get what I want when I use a file for the JSON data.  I run the get_books.php file in the console and paste output into a JSON.txt file. When I then have ajax: "./JSON.txt", things work fine!  I suppose for a small dataset I could just use the file and cause it to be updated at the end?  But, I wanted to be able to use the JSON returned from the get_books.php.  It doesn't give me a parse error, but it doesn't fill in the data either.

Comment: I ran my get_books.php output through JSONLint and it said it was valid.

Comment: @JohnWooten, make sure you have included calls to `header()` to set content type of the response.

Comment: I did. It shouldn't be this complicated to do things using these frameworks. I can write it all from "scratch" with less effort and uncertainty. The frameworks should make it easier. Instead, it's a guessing game.

Comment: What causes the script to run the get_books.php instead if just reading it?  It seems you would have to execute the php code. How do you do that?

Comment: @JohnWooten, I have a feeling that the path to `get_books.php` is incorrect. Specify full path to script, for example `"ajax": "/full/path/to/get_books.php"` and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem and it was stupid on my part!
On OS X El Capitan ( 10.11.2 ), php files were NOT getting recognized by Safari or any other browser because they were in my home directory and not in the /Library/WebServer/Documents root for apache!

I moved my project into that directory as I could not get things set up to use my user directory ~/Sites as you could before El Capitan ( will work on that some more in the future ).

With that change, the php documents get executed as they are included in the ajax argument and all works fine!

Thanks every one for your help.  Sorry to have wasted time, but my test.php worked, but I hadn't noticed that it was in the web server root directory!